# Using rmoo to solve Multi- objective Knapsack problem

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to get my head round using `rmoo` / MOGAs so want to try and apply it to a simple example:

> given a knapsack with weight capacity 50, how can we select items which maximise profit and desirability whilst remaining under the weight limit?

My data:

| Items | Profit | Desirability | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| i1 | 9 | 28 | 17 |
| i2 | 27 | 62 | 1 |
| i3 | 41 | 20 | 28 |
| i4 | 15 | 29 | 4 |
| i5 | 38 | 42 | 21 |
| i6 | 6 | 60 | 26 |
| i7 | 4 | 65 | 22 |
| i8 | 35 | 100 | 5 |
| i9 | 43 | 78 | 12 |
| i10 | 13 | 31 | 15 |
| i11 | 7 | 12 | 14 |
| i12 | 25 | 80 | 25 |
| i13 | 31 | 44 | 30 |
| i14 | 37 | 74 | 19 |
| i15 | 28 | 26 | 2 |

My code:

```
# objective func
fitness=function(x){
  f1 = current_profit=sum(x%*%data$profit)
  f2 = current_desirability=sum(x%*%data$des)
  current_weight=sum(x%*%data$weight)
  if(current_weight>weightlimit){
    return(c(f1 = 0,f2 = 0))
  } else { 
      return(c(f1=f1,f2=f2))} 
}
```

The fitness function returns a vector total_profit, total_des if the weight constraint is not broken:

```
result <- nsga2(type = "binary",
                fitness = fitness,
                nBits = 15,
                popSize = 100, 
                monitor = FALSE,
                maxiter = 500)
```

however, I get the error:

> "Error in x %*% data$profit : non-conformable arguments"

I think I'm going wrong with my fitness function. Am I not supposed to return a 1 by 2 vector? If I sum the total_profit & total_desirability at the final step of the fitness function (to get a single value), how is this different to a normal GA rather than MOGA?